# JavaScript: Display positive numbers with the plus sign

Tags: javascript, numbers

How would I display positive number such as 3 as +3 and negative numbers such -5 as -5? So, as follows:

1, 2, 3 goes into +1, +2, +3

but if those are

-1, -2, -3 then goes into -1, -2, -3

Comment: How do you want to display `0`? Most seem to assume that it should be displayed as just `0` rather than `+0`.

Answer (score 61):

You can use a simple expression like this:

```
(n<0?"":"+") + n
```

The conditional expression results in a plus sign if the number is positive, and an empty string if the number is negative.

You haven't specified how to handle zero, so I assumed that it would be displayed as `+0`. If you want to display it as just `0`, use the `<=` operator instead:

```
(n<=0?"":"+") + n
```

Answer (score 23):

```
// Forces signing on a number, returned as a string
function getNumber(theNumber)
{
    if(theNumber > 0){
        return "+" + theNumber;
    }else{
        return theNumber.toString();
    }
}
```

This will do it for you.

Comment: Thank god someone realized that negative numbers already are 'signed' :)

Answer (score 23):

A modern solution would be to use Intl.NumberFormat

```
const myNumber = 5;

new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    signDisplay: "exceptZero"
}).format(myNumber);
```

depending on what `myNumber` is it will display positive or negative sign, except when it's a 0.

Comment: Would be ideal but has only 87% browser support. Safari & Chrome on iOS didn't support this until 2021-04-26.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Other values for signDisplay include "always", "never", and "negative".

Answer (score 6):

```
printableNumber = function(n) { return (n > 0) ? "+" + n : n; };
```

Answer (score 4):

write a js function to do it for you?

something like

```
var presentInteger = function(toPresent) {
    if (toPresent > 0) return "+" + toPresent;
    else return "" + toPresent;
}
```

you could also use the conditional operator:

```
var stringed = (toPresent > 0) ? "+" + toPresent : "" + toPresent;
```

Thanx to the comments for pointing out that "-" + toPresent would put a double -- on the string....

Answer (score 3):

```
function format(n) {
    return (n>0?'+':'') + n;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
['','+'][+(num > 0)] + num
```

or

```js
['','+'][Number(num > 0)] + num
```

It is a shorter form than the ternary operator, based on casting boolean to the number 0 or 1 and using it as an index of an array with prefixes, for a number greater than 0 the prefix '+' is used

Comment: that's clever way of doing it but I'd still say ternary operator is preferable, again just my opinion

Comment: `[['+'][number & 0x80000000], number].join('')` based on your idea

Answer (score 1):

The solution with the ternary operator seems just fine, but for the fun of it, here is another one:

```
('+'+x).replace("+-", "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

something along the lines of:

```
if (num > 0)
{
   numa = "+" + num;
}
else
{
   numa = num.toString();
}
```

and then print the string `numa`.

Comment: This will display as `+3`, `+2`, `+1`, `-0`, `--1`, `--2`, `--3` etc.

Comment: This would return `--5` for input `-5`.

Comment: I've just run another test as well, it returns **--6** for **-6**

Comment: yeah sorry, wrote in a hurry while reading something else.  Sorted now, only modify it if it's above 0.

Answer (score -1):

Modern syntax solution.

It also includes a space between sign and number:

```
function getNumberWithSign(input) {
  if (input === 0) {
    return "0"
  }

  const sign = input < 0 ? '-' : '+';

  return `${sign} ${Math.abs(input)}`;
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.