# Adding a plus "+" symbol to positive numbers in a JQuery output

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a modified Jquery UI Slider Bar (-100 to +100). When the user moves the slider up and down the scale they receive visual feedback via a `<div id="slider-result"></div>`

Currently the `slider-result` displays the `-` symbol when the number is negative e.g. `-47`, but it does not display the `+` symbol when the number is positive e.g. `61`

**How can I make `slider-result` display the `+` symbol immediately before the number when it is positive?**

[I have looked at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347016/javascript-display-positive-numbers-with-the-plus-sign) but when I try to integrate the solution it  displays the `+` when the number is positive, but it stops displaying the number...

**My Attempt**

```
slide: function(event, ui) { 
  $("#slider-result").html(ui.value>0?'+':'') + ui.value;
```

Any helps is as always, much appriciated. Thanks

**Edit** - My complete code

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var username = $('#hidden').val();
    if (username == "") username = 0;  //SHOULD THIS STILL BE 0?
    $.post('comment.php', {
        hidden: username
    }, function(return_data) {
        alert(return_data);
    });
});

$(".slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: -100,
    max: +100,
    step: 1,

    slide: function(event, ui) { 
      $("#slider-result").html(ui.value>0?'+':'') + ui.value;

      //this updates the hidden form field so I can submit the data using a form
      if($(this).attr("id") ==  "one")
          $("#hidden1").val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post a complete code example so that we can reproduce what you're seeing?

Comment: Have you inspected the output to make sure that the missing numbers aren't just being cut off in their div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to include the `+ ui.value;` inside of the parentheses as well:

```
$("#slider-result").html((ui.value>0?'+':'') + ui.value);
```

Since you only have the `'+'` or `''` inside of the `html()` method, it will only put those values and not include the actual value.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it now that you've edited it, I just added a fiddle that shows it working, as I tested it before answering.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the `ui.value` inside the html function:

```
$("#slider-result").html(ui.value>0?'+' + ui.value:'' + ui.value);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qhq92aam/1/)**