# Convert string to number but keep '+' using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I am converting the following string to a number, but it is removing the "+" character. My intent is to have the following output:

What I am currently getting back:

```
"change": "+0.01",
```

My desired output:

```
"change": +0.01,
```

Using "Number()" with remove the "+"

How do I pull this off?

Comment: In simple words, You cannot achieve this. `+0.01` is a string, not a number

Comment: _"My desired output"_ Is that text? A part of an object? Some JSON? What? Be clear. Ideally present your [MCVE]; you've been here for five and a half years, and asked 87 questions, so you should know by now what we expect.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Don't provide solutions in the comments section, as we cannot peer review them properly. For example, I cannot downvote your wrong comment; that suggestion will result in a string, which the OP stated they are trying to get away from.

Answer (score 2):

A number is a number is a number. Not a string. Not a representation of a number. But a number. There is no "+" character or "-" character stored with it. There are no commas, or periods, or other characters. It is a *number*. You can't have "plus symbol two apples"; you just have two apples.

The number 0.01 is positive. It is irrelevant where that number came from, or what the original string looked like that was used to produce the number.

If you wish to stringise a positive number with a leading `+`, then that is about how you deal with the `Number` object later when you later "convert" it back to a string. [You can achieve that simply with an `if` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4347066/560648).

However to me your "desired outcome" looks like an object declaration, in which the presence or not of a leading `+` would again be irrelevant, as you are storing a *number*. You can format it however you like at the receiving end of the data, if you need to present it to a human.

Comment: Not really. Number can have a period and `-` sign if it is negative. `+` sign can be placed by hand to force type coercion.

Comment: @DamianCzapiewski: You are mistaken and missed the entire point.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `+0.01` is equal to `0.01`. If you want to keep `+` then you need it to be string.

If you want to get number from that string and check if it has `+` sign then use RegEx or [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) that string.

Answer (score 0):

A `+` prefix for numbers would be a terrible idea in JavaScript, that is why it is not allowed.

In this language, `+` is already used for many things like:

- String **concatenation** (e.g. `'foo' + 'bar'`)
- **Addition** of numbers (e.g. `1 + 2`)
- Variable **increment** (e.g. `i++`)
- Explicit type **conversion** with the *unary operator* (e.g. `+'0.07'`)
- Implicit type conversion (**coercion**) when operands are not of the same type (e.g. `4 + '6'`)

This is an error-prone part of JavaScript because you may have code like this:

```js
var i = 2;

console.log(+'+1' + '3' + ++i + +'7');
```

There are two exceptions, however:

1. `+0`, which is not the same thing as `-0` (see `Object.is(+0, -0)`)
2. Exponential numbers (see `Object.is(1e+2, 100)`)

In your case, `Number('+0.01')` or `parseFloat('+0.01')` will return `0.01`. This is the expected (and reasonable) behavior.